# CV problem in LIBSVM

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I am using LIBSVM for regression problem. Based on the codes provides in their FAQ, the grid search is like this:

```
bestcv = 0;
for log2c = -1:3,
  for log2g = -4:1,
    cmd = ['-v 5 -c ', num2str(2^log2c), ' -g ', num2str(2^log2g)];
    cv = svmtrain(heart_scale_label, heart_scale_inst, cmd);
    if (cv >= bestcv),
      bestcv = cv; bestc = 2^log2c; bestg = 2^log2g;
    end
    fprintf('%g %g %g (best c=%g, g=%g, rate=%g)\n', log2c, log2g, cv, bestc, bestg, bestcv);
  end
end
```

with the codes above I always got the worst results, then I changed to the following and everthing works well.

```
bestcv = inf;...

if (cv <= bestcv)...
```

In my sense cv is a score, more is better, and should be less than 1(100%). But in my case cv becomes like error, less is better, and some are bigger than 1. It's so weird, maybe I did something wrong? or can I keep my codes and results like mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I checked svmtrain.c, in case of regression problem, cv is error(MSE), lower the better. And in case of classification problem, cv is accuracy, higher the better. Therefore I did everything right.